# Programmatic instantiation of custom UITableViewController with cell prototypes created using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a segue (called `"ToSettingsSegue"`) that pushes a custom view controller (`SettingsTableViewController`) onto a `UINavigationController`'s stack.  `SettingsTableViewController` has prototype cells (`"prototypeSliderCell"`) set up.  It goes without saying that this is setup in a storyboard.

Another section of code pushes `SettingsTableViewController` onto the `UINavigationController`'s stack programmatically.  In `SettingTableViewController`'s `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, `-dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns nil when this is done programmatically.

I assume this occurs due to the prototype cells not being available programmatically.

My workaround?  Calling `-perfromeSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and sending `"ToSettingsSegue"` and self.

Is there a better solution to this problem?  I cannot help but feel that this is dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your SettingsTableViewController in code rather than through a storyboard segue the prototype cell definition is not available since it is only defined in your storyboard.

The "workaround" you describe should work fine, and I see nothing dirty about it.  There are plenty of instances where you'll want to programmatically trigger a storyboard segue to happen, and that's what `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` was designed to handle.